# NodeBB - Post Reputation/Likes - Find which users liked a post

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, nodebb

I am not able to find where does NodeBB stores the list of users who liked a particular post. 
For example, consider following data structure:-

```
> db.objects.find({_key:"post:2341"}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5547af3f65190fe2122d0b3c"),
    "_key" : "post:2341",
    "edited" : 0,
    "pid" : 2341,
    "content" : "content of this post",
    "tid" : 2543,
    "timestamp" : 1412304172707,
    "deleted" : 0,
    "editor" : "",
    "uid" : 747,
    "toPid" : 19999,
    "votes" : 0,
    "reputation" : 5
}
```

The above says that Post ID `2341` has `5` reputations which means it is liked by `5` users. But where does it stores that these are the User IDs who liked this particular post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally hunted down for the exact key that stores it in the database via going through NodeBB code. And the particular key that stores it is `pid:{postid}:upvote`. So we query like this:-

```
>db.objects.find({_key: "pid:2341:upvote"})
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5547af3f65190fe2122d0b3c"),
    "_key": "pid:2341:upvote",
    "members": ["663", "230", "549"]
}
```

The above response contains the IDs of the users who upvoted a particular post.